# Android TableLayout not Displaying

Tags: android, view, tablelayout, visible

I've got a class whose content is set to a layout which has a few buttons and a TableLayout.

The real work that makes the TableLayout is in a separate static helper class, which has a method that returns the desired table.

However, the table is not displaying. What humiliatingly simple fact am I missing?

Here is the class whose content is set to the layout:

```
public class TesterActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
        table = TableHelper.getTable_BINARY_NUMBERS(getApplicationContext(), 5, 25);
    }
}
```

And here is the helper class that creates the Table's meat:

```
public class TableHelper {

    public static TableLayout getTable_BINARY_NUMBERS(Context context, int numRows, int numCols) {

        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(context);

        table.setStretchAllColumns(true);  
        table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);  

        TableRow[] rows = new TableRow[numRows];
        for (int row=0; row<numRows; row++) {
            rows[row] = new TableRow(context);

            for (int col=0; col<numCols-1; col++) {
                TextView num = new TextView(context);
                num.setText("0");
                rows[row].addView(num);
            }
            TextView rowText = new TextView(context);
            rowText.setText("Row " + (row + 1));
            rowText.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
            rows[row].addView(rowText);
            rows[row].setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
            table.addView(rows[row]);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a new table layout, pass the one you get right away to your `getTable_BINARY_NUMBERS()` and modify it in your method instead of returning a completely new one.

Answer (score 1):

The `TableLayout` your helper class is returning is not the same as the `TableLayout` that you are seeing.

when you do `setContentView(R.layout.main);` an instance of `TableLayout` is created which you assign to the variable table. The `TableLayout` coming from your helper class is a different instance.

Comment: so, would I have to pass the table as an argument to my helper class method?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do. But ya passing `table` might help you.